# The name 'IsPost' does not exist in the current context

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, debian, yeoman

I am trying to get started writing MVC apps using .Net Core. I'm sure the answer will be obvious to anybody with any experience.

This script builds a web application, adds a controller and a view, which all works well for me. It also replaces the contents of the view with what I think the tutorials are trying to teach me. Anyway, i'm struggling to overcome the error that i'm getting; "The name 'IsPost' does not exist in the current context".

Here's my script...

```
cd ~/Desktop
yo aspnet web problemDemo
cd problemDemo
yo aspnet:MvcController MyForm
mkdir Views/MyForm
yo aspnet:MvcView MyForm/Index
echo """
@{
  if (IsPost) {
    &lt;h1&gt;Is Post&lt;/h1&gt;
  } else {
    &lt;h1&gt;Not Post&lt;/h1&gt;
  }
}
""" > Views/MyForm/Index.cshtml
dotnet restore
dotnet build
export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
dotnet run
```

...and I get the error by browsing to...

```
http://localhost:5000/MyForm
```

I am trying this on Debian. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Well you are trying to use a variable/method called `IsPost` in your view. Where does that come from? It's not in there my default.

Comment: Oh, I think i've wandered off into a tutorial that doesn't relate to what i'm trying to learn. I was looking here: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_forms.asp